# convert long to timestamp when downloading dates from BigQuery - java

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am downloading data from bigquery. 
using the `com.google.cloud.bigquery` library
using the following code:

```
    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM `datasetId.tableId` where field=val;";
    BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    // Create a query request
    QueryRequest queryRequest =
            QueryRequest.newBuilder(queryString)
                    .setMaxWaitTime(60000L)
                    .setPageSize(1000L)
                    .setUseLegacySql(false)
                    .build();
    // Request query to be executed and wait for results
    QueryResponse queryResponse = bigquery.query(queryRequest);
    while (!queryResponse.jobCompleted()) {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        queryResponse = bigquery.getQueryResults(queryResponse.getJobId());
    }
    // Read rows
    Iterator<List<FieldValue>> rowIterator = queryResponse.getResult().iterateAll();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(rowIterator.next());
    }
```

In bigquery this is my data :

`{time: "2017-01-18 08:28:55 UTC", date: "2016-09-22 14:37:52 UTC"}`

when I download I get this value:

```
time -> "1.484728135674E9" date -> "1.474555072424E9"
```

So i tried converting using this code:

```
private String convert(String value) {
    long lng = (long) Double.parseDouble(value);
    Date date = new Date(lng * 1000);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

but i get this:

```
 time ->"2017-01-18T10:28:55.000Z" date -> "2016-09-22T17:37:52.000Z"
```

(one date is in 2 hrs diff and the other 3 hrs diff!!??!!)

how can I get the original values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the timezone. BigQuery stores its timestamps in UTC, so you need to specify the UTC TimeZone on your formatter:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormatUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
   dateFormatUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

   System.out.println("time: " + dateFormatUTC.format(new Date(Double.valueOf("1.484728135674E9").longValue() * 1000)));
   System.out.println("date: " + dateFormatUTC.format(new Date(Double.valueOf("1.474555072424E9").longValue() * 1000)));
}
```

**Prints**:

```
time: 2017-01-18T08:28:55.000Z
date: 2016-09-22T14:37:52.000Z
```

If you're using Java 8, then you can use `Instant`, which is based on UTC anyway:

```
..
System.out.println("time: " + Instant.ofEpochMilli(Double.valueOf("1.484728135674E9").longValue() * 1000));
System.out.println("date: " + Instant.ofEpochMilli(Double.valueOf("1.474555072424E9").longValue() * 1000));
..
```

**Prints**:

```
time: 2017-01-18T08:28:55Z
date: 2016-09-22T14:37:52Z
```